# How to call images in public folder in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

My question is very simple

I am trying to call this source in my public folder in img folder:

```
src="img/vcc3logo.png"
```

But I can't display it on my pdf print form

When the customer print for a certification form it needed to display the image. The file of the print.blade.php is located in resources/views/customer-relations/dashboard/print.blade.php

Here is the code in my print.blade.php

```
    {{--   <div class="content">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="box-body"> --}}

            <img src="" height="50" width="50" style="float: right">
            <img src="img/vcc3logo.png" height="50" width="50" style="float: left">

            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="text-center">
                <p class="text-center maliit">
                Republic of the Philippines<br>
                 National Capital Region<br>
                <font>City Government of Valenzuela</font><br>
                   Office of the City Mayor<br>
            Valenzuela City Command and Communications Center<br>
    2nd Floor, City ALERT Center, Mc-Arthur Hi-way, Malinta, Valenzuela City<br>
    </p>
                    <h3>Application Number:{{ $application_number }}</h3>
                </div>
                <h5><b>Business Name:</b> {{ $business_name }}</h5>
                <h5><b>Owner:</b> {{ $owner }}</h5>
                <h5><b>Location:</b> {{ $location }}</h5>
                </span>
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Fees</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th class="text-center"></th>
                            <th class="text-center"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-9"><em>Inspection Fee:</em></h4></td>
                            <td class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center"></td>
                            <td class="col-md-1 text-center"></td>
                            <td class="col-md-1 text-center">{{ $inspection_fee }}</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-9"><em>Certificate Fee:</em></h4></td>
                            <td class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center"></td>
                            <td class="col-md-1 text-center"></td>
                            <td class="col-md-1 text-center">{{ $cert_fee }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-9"><em>Local Fee:</em></h4></td>
                            <td class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center"></td>
                            <td class="col-md-1 text-center"></td>
                            <td class="col-md-1 text-center">{{ $local_fee }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-9"><em>Others Fee:</em></h4></td>
                            <td class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center"></td>
                            <td class="col-md-1 text-center"></td>
                            <td class="col-md-1 text-center">{{ $others_fee }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <p><i>Note: Please print and present to Customer Relations Officer</i></p>
                </td>
            </div>
        {{-- </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 --}}
```

I tried to change it to

```
src="url('/img/cctv_camera.jpg')"
```

but ended up with this error:

(1/1) RuntimeException
The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "Loading pages (1/6)

Answer (score 1):

If image file is located inside public folder then you need to add `asset()` which give full path of image like

```
<img src="{{asset('/img/vcc3logo.png')}}" height="50" width="50" style="float: left">
```

Comment: Thanks! Never heard of that. I am just new to Laravel. But it takes time to reload the page when I change the code to src="{{asset('/img/vcc3logo.png')}}"

Comment: @JayzdeVera Any way congrats. If you have got solution to your problem then please do not forgot to close question by accepting it later :)

Comment: btw I ended up with this error :

(1/1) ProcessTimedOutException
The process "/home/jayzdevera/Documents/CrudCCTV/cctv-crud/web/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --lowquality '/tmp/knp_snappy598a76187aacc3.07751285.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy598a76187ab6d4.11019290.pdf'" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.

When I changed the code to src="{{asset('/img/vcc3logo.png')}}

Comment: @JayzdeVera It seems problem with your pdf generation. does pdf size is too large or computation is complex and don't complete in 60 second

Comment: @JayzdeVera See this issue in github https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/105

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this hope its help for you :

```
<img src="{{url('')}}/img/vcc3logo.png" height="50" width="50" style="float: left">
```

**OR**

```
<img src="{{asset('/img/vcc3logo.png')}}" height="50" width="50" style="float: left">
```

Hope this work for you !!!